# How to Get the Second Field of a Tuple in Rust?

Tags: rust, tuples

I'm trying to copy only one section of an array, and I got kind of lost when one of the methods returned a tuple with two generics instead of an array.

Here's the code:

```rust
for i in 0..v.len() {
    stack = Vecthing::clone_vec(&v)
                       .as_mut_slice()
                       .split_at(i)
                       .B// aware this doesn't work just showing where I try to access the second field
                       .iter()
                       .collect();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust tuples can be indexed by `.` followed by their index, in your case:

```
for i in 0..v.len() {
    stack = Vecthing::clone_vec(&v)
                       .as_mut_slice()
                       .split_at(i)
                       .1
                       .iter()
                       .collect();
}
```

(As your example is not reproducible, I cannot easily verify my answer.)

For more information, see [the Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/tuple-expr.html).

Comment: Yes, but don't clone the whole Vec at the beginning. You iter and collect, combine it with cloned() or copied().

Comment: Or slice and clone. (&v[i..]).to_vec(), if there is nothing done in iteration.